# not able to install WALinuxAgent on my mac

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machine, agent

This may sound really stupid but i don't know how can i set this up on my mac?? I'm running macOS Sierra Version 10.12.1. I've an ubuntu vm on my azure portal (created using classic mode, back in 2014) and i've my site hosted there. For some reason, my site is not reachable and I'm not able to connect to my VM either.
I want to reset the remote access settings and ssh passwords but Azure portal tells me to install this Linux Agent to manage that. And i'm totally lost here.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out here.

Thanks

Comment: Is the VM running?

Answer (score 0):

Can describe your issue a bit more in detail?
What exactly are you trying/have you tried and what is the outcome.

The WALinuxAgent souldnt run on your mac but inside your Azure VM. The waagent is the agent which enables the azure fabric to talk to your VM. This grants you the ability to reset password or admin keys throught the Portal.

Comment: Hey Tobi, Thanks for getting back!. I have a VM in azure (ubuntu) - build with classic mode. I want to reset the password, since i don't remember the password to the vm and also no possibility to connect to the vm using ssh. My website is down (not reachable) and i don't know what is the issue, so i want to connect to the vm to see if i can get any information.

Comment: When i m picking up the option to reset the password, i get this message: "The VM agent is required for this operation; install the VM Agent from here: http://aka.ms/vmagentlinux.". I don't know how to install that in Azure VM, since I have no way to get into the VM at the moment, and i don't seem to find option from the portal to let me install the agent.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, we can **add a user** to this VM, use the new user to login this VM, then upgrade the Azure Linux Agent.
Here are my steps to add a new user to this VM:
1. Delete the VM and keep the attached disks. 
Then **backup this VHD**(more important, backup), we can use Azure Storage Explorer to copy this VHD and save as another name.
[image]
2. create a new VM(VM1), and mount the ubuntu VM's OS disk to this VM.
 Then add user in **/etc/passwd** **/etc/group /etc/shadow** and create home folder for new user, then add user in **/etc/sudoers**. Finally, we can unmount the VHD, and use this VHD to deploy a VM, then we can use the new user to login Azure VM, and install walinuxagent on it.
More information about how to install walinuxagent, refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-agent-user-guide).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.